# Incredibly slow runtime on text search [Optimization]

Tags: java, search, optimization, text

## What am I trying to do

I have a huge text file of size 8.5 GB containing 3 million lines in the format of a word, followed by 300 numbers, like this:

word 0.056646 -0.0256464 0.05246 (and so on)

The 300 numbers behind the word form a vector that represent the word. I have 3 words with which I must find the vector that represents the 4th word most closely, using an analogy model (I'm using addition, multiplication and direction).

For addition, it would look like this:

Say you have the word vectors a, b and c, then I would do c - a + b. I will then iterate through all 3 million lines and use the cosine similarity to find the fourth word d by looking for the maximum result. So it looks like this: d = max(cos(d', c-a+b)) where d' stands for the word at the current line.

## What is the problem

The example stated above represents one query.  I have to perform a total of 20000 queries. And I'm not just performing it for the addition analogy model, but for multiplication and direction as well.  When I run my program, it's still trying to calculate the 4th word for the first analogy model (addition) for the first query, after a total of 30 seconds! I'm in dire need of optimizations in my program.

First, I'm doing a simple iteration over the 3 million lines (3 times) to find the vector I need for the word vectors a, b and c. Using *System.nanoTime()* I learn that for each of these vectors it takes about 1.5 milliseconds to find a vector. That's about 5 milliseconds to find all 3.

Next, I do a calculation between vectors, using classes I wrote myself (I did not seem to find any standard API that handles vector calculations):

```
public class VectorCalculation {

    public static List<Double> plus(List<Double> v1, List<Double> v2){
        return operation(new Plus(), v1, v2);
    }

    public static List<Double> minus(List<Double> v1, List<Double> v2){
        return operation(new Minus(), v1, v2);
    }

    public static List<Double> operation(Operator op, List<Double> v1, List<Double> v2){
        if(v1.size() != v2.size())  throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dimension of the given lists are not the same.");
        List<Double> resultVector = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++){
            resultVector.add(op.calculate(v1.get(i), v2.get(i)));
        }
        return resultVector;
    }
}

public interface Operator {
    public Double calculate(Double e1, Double e2);
}

public class Plus implements Operator {

    @Override
    public Double calculate(Double e1, Double e2) {
        return e1+e2;
    }
}

public class Minus implements Operator {

    @Override
    public Double calculate(Double e1, Double e2) {
        return e1-e2;
    }
}
```

The calculation of the vector is here:

```
public class Addition extends AnalogyModel {

    @Override
    double calculateWordVector(List<Double> a, List<Double> b, List<Double> c, List<Double> d) {
        //long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        List<Double> result = VectorCalculation.plus(VectorCalculation.minus(c, a), b);
        //long endTime1 = System.nanoTime() - startTime1;
        double result2 = cosineSimilarity(d, result);
        //long endTime2 = System.nanoTime() - startTime1;
        //System.out.println(endTime1 + "       |       " + endTime2);
        return result2;
    }

    Double cosineSimilarity(List<Double> v1, List<Double> v2){
        if(v1.size() != v2.size())  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Vector dimensions are not the same.");

        // find the dividend
        Double dividend = dotProduct(v1, v2);

        // find the divisor
        Double divisor = dotProduct(v1, v1) * dotProduct(v2, v2);
        if(divisor == 0)    divisor = 0.0001;   // safety net against dividing by 0.

        return dividend/divisor;
    }

    /**
     * @return  Returns the dot product of two vectors.
     */
    Double dotProduct(List<Double> v1, List<Double> v2){
        System.out.println(v1);
        Double result = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++){
            result += v1.get(i)*v2.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The time it takes to calculate *result* starts out rough (at about 0.1 milliseconds) but soon drops to about 0.025 milliseconds. The time it takes to calculate *result2* is usually pretty modest as well around 0.005 milliseconds.  d' is found by iterating through the 3 million lines and saving the vector list.  This operation takes about 0.06 milliseconds.

To summarize: the estimated time it takes to finish one query, for one analogy model, it takes 5 + 3000000*(0.025 + 0.005 + 0.06) = 270005 milliseconds or 270 seconds or 4.5 minutes to finish ONE query...  Considering I need to do this two more times for the other analogy models and I need to do that a total of 20000 times, this is clearly not sufficient.

The words in the text file are not ordered.  It seems like the vector computation is too heavy, but the time it takes to find the vector of a word in the text file must be shortened as well. Would it help if the text file were split up in smaller ones?

### Update - Code to reading file

```
    /**
     * @param vocabularyPath    The path of the vector text file.
     * @param word              The word to find the vector for.
     * @return  Returns the vector of the given word as an array list.
     */
    List<Double> getStringVector(String vocabularyPath, String word) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vocabularyPath));

        String input = br.readLine();
        boolean found = false;
        while(!found && input != null){
            if(input.contains(word))    found = true;
            else input = br.readLine();
        }

        br.close();
        if(input == null)   return null;
        else return getVector(input);
    }

    /**
     * @param inputLine A line from the vector text file.
     * @return  Returns the vector of the given line as an array list.
     */
    List<Double> getVector(String inputLine){
        String[] splitString = inputLine.split("\\s+");
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(splitString));
        stringList.remove(0); // remove the word at the front
        stringList.remove(stringList.size()-1); // remove the empty string at the end
        List<Double> vectorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : stringList){
            vectorList.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
        }
        return vectorList;
    }
```

Comment: _8.5 GB containing 3 million lines_ That is going to take a long time, no matter what you do.

Comment: I don't think the performance issues would be in the calculations, but mainly in reading the file, no? Can you show that code? I see also you use list.get(i), make sure you don't use LinkedList...

Comment: @JPMoresmau I have added the code to how vectors are read from the file.

Comment: If you're reading the source file each time to find a word, wouldn't you better off putting everything into a database with an index on word? You'll pay the price of importing once but then lookups would be fast. You can use a simple database like H2 or sqllite.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Interesting suggestion!  I didn't know about it.  I'll try it and report back my findings.

Comment: In the end I decided not to use Java for the task.  Python's C arrays were able to search much faster for some reason.  It was able to finish the whole task in 50 minutes.  Relatively speaking, this is very fast, considering I did not break up the text file into smaller parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious problems: `List<Double>` and `Operator`.

The first means that instead of using 8 bytes for a `double` (btw. `float` would most probably do), you need more than twice as much (an object containing the value and a reference). What's worse: You lose space locality as your number may anywhere in the memory.

The second means that you for each dot product perform N virtual calls. This mayn't be a current problem, but when you switch between operators, it may slow you down a lot.

### Recommendation

I guess all your vectors are equally long, so use a `double[]`. You save tons of memory and get a nice speedup.

Rewrite your `operation` to something like

```
public static void operationTo(double[] result, Operator op, double[] v1, double[] v2){
    int length = result.length;
    if(v1.length != length || v2.length != length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The dimension of the given lists are not the same.");
    }
    switch (op) { // use an enum
        case PLUS:
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                result[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
            }
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

### Word lookup

The fastest way is a `HashMap<String, double[]>`, assuming it all fits into memory. Otherwise, a database (as already suggested) could be the way to go. A sorted file with a binary search would do as well. However, note that any other solution than a `Map` is 10+ times slower.

#### Word lookup in case memory is tight

You have 3M words only, which fits into memory nicely. Place them into an `ArrayList` and sort it. Write the vectors into a binary file ordered the the words. Now, to find a vector, all you need to do is

```
long index = Arrays.binarySeach(wordList, word);
randomAccessFile.seek(index * vectorLength * Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE)
```

Comment: I have tried both of these solutions, none of them work for me I'm afraid.  I get a memory out of bounds exception when my hashmap reaches about 700000th line (2.3 million to go).  The H2 database has been setup, but my queries take about as long as my original solution..

Comment: I am looping through the entire database since I need to compare with every single line, with the following line: ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(String.format("select * from %s", fileID));

The program stays stuck on that line computing for a very long time.

Comment: @Babyburger You know the java `-Xmx` switch, right? Can't you simply get more memory, it's most probably way cheaper than your time. Concerning the DB, your query looks like if you created one table per row... I guess, you should update your question so that we know more.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to answer 20000 [nearest neighbor searches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) in a set of 3 million coordinates in a 300-dimensional space?

Iterating over the entire dataset for each query is bound to be rather slow. You'll probably get the biggest speedup by inserting the dataset into a data structure that can answer nearest neighbor queries efficiently, such as a [Ball Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree).

Comment: There are "only" 300 dimensions. I'm rather sceptical because of the really high dimensionality. I also wonder if the construction overhead doesn't dominate the cost of "only" 20000 searches. OTOH, doing `20e3 * 3e6 * 300 = 1.8e13` multiplications is really a bit too much.

Comment: Right, it is 300 dimensions. Have edited that. I don't expect construction overhead to dominate, because most such algorithms are O(n log n), albeit with a rather high constant factor, but the naive algorithm is O(nk), where k is the number of searches. Since log(n) = 20 is much smaller than k = 20000, I'd expect construction overhead to be significantly smaller than effort of querying.

Comment: You're probably right, though the constant factor may be damn high (cache misses, branch mispredictions, maybe even random disk access). And there's a programming overhead and a non-trivial chance of getting something wrong. With current i7 having hundreds of GFLOPS, `1.8e13` is not that much (though it'd possibly need some xmm fused mac assembly). I'd be inclined to let my computer get hot overnight.